# Google Indexed My website's IP and Showing IP as backlink in Search Console

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, backlinks

Google has Indexed my  My Website's IP address.

Google has about 100 pages of my IP address, as well as my domain, indexed.  Somehow in Google Search Console my IP address is working as Backlink to my website. My website got more than 10000 backlinks from my own IP address which is very bad for my website SEO.

Comment: I recommend either 404ing or 301-redirecting requests that come in for the bare ip.

Comment: It looks like you already redirect from the IP address URL to the domain URL.  Has that been in place for long?